# how to make webview_flutter use wideviewport?

Tags: flutter, webview, viewport, webview-flutter

when I load my Wix website using **webview_flutter** it doesn't take fullscreen, but it works using **flutter_webview_plugin**, and I figured that the problem is that **webview_flutter** doesn't set **wide viewport** natively `webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);`
so how can i make it use this wide viewport?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after 24 hours of debugging i was able to acheive the desired effect by forking the package and modifying the native code myself.

the modification was on the file **WebViewBuilder.java** and simply adding the line `webStettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);` to activate the wideviewport

Answer (score 2):

If you control the html yourself that is loaded (or it's just some embed code), try adding the viewport meta tag in the head; for example:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport"  content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
</head>
<body>
<script async="" src="https://url-to-the-embed-code-you-are-using"></script>
</body>
</html>
```